# Knockout.JS custom bindings. Updating foreach

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js

I'm trying to parse the object, which come from JSON file. It looks like this:

```
[
{
//Rest of data
    "Screenshots":
    [
        ["wp_ss_20160408_0001.png","wp_ss_20160408_0002.png","wp_ss_20160408_0003.png"]
    ]
//Rest of data
},
{
//Rest of data
    "Screenshots":
    [
        ["wp_ss_20160414_0027.png","wp_ss_20160414_0028.png","wp_ss_20160414_0029.png"]
    ]
//Rest  of data
},
{
//Rest of data
    "Screenshots":
    [
        ["wp_ss_20160410_0002.png","wp_ss_20160410_0003.png","wp_ss_20160410_0004.png"],
        ["",
        "",
        ""]
    ]
//Rest of data
}
]
```

As you can see, I have objects, which contains "Screenshots" property. All of them will come in several language support. I mean, 5 screenshots for English, 5 or 4 for other language etc. I'm displaying this model in Javascript like this:

```
    ko.bindingHandlers.getLocalizedScreenshot = 
{
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext)
    {
        ko.cleanNode(element);         
        var observe = ko.observableArray();   
        var languageIndex = self.displayLanguages.indexOf(self.currentLanguage());
        observe
        (
            languageIndex>valueAccessor().length-1? valueAccessor()[0] : valueAccessor()[languageIndex] 
        );
        ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, {foreach: observe})
       return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };            
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext)
    {
        ko.cleanNode(element);
        var observe = ko.observableArray();   
        var languageIndex = self.displayLanguages.indexOf(self.currentLanguage());
        observe
        (
            languageIndex>valueAccessor().length-1? valueAccessor()[0] : valueAccessor()[languageIndex] 
        );
        ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, {foreach: observe})
        return { controlsDescendantBindings: false};        
    }
};
```

And my HTML looks like

```
<!--Rest of markup -->
        <div class="screenshots" data-bind="getLocalizedScreenshot:Screenshots">
            <div class="holderImg">
                <img data-bind="attr:{src:'images/projects/'+$data}" alt="image"> 
                <div class="increaseSize">
                    <div class="zoomHolder">
                        <img src="images/zoom.png" alt="images/zoom.png">
                        <div>Zoom</div>                   
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<!-- Rest of markup -->
```

But I something messed up. Because it duplicates pictures. How should I be able to track the update event of `self.currentLanguage()`and according to this show new screenshots?

Here's the screenshot of problem:
[image: knockout js problem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. Just use the built-in foreach update method :

```
    ko.bindingHandlers.getLocalizedScreenshot = 
{
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext)
    {
        var languageIndex = self.displayLanguages.indexOf(self.currentLanguage());
        var array = ko.observableArray(languageIndex>valueAccessor().length-1? valueAccessor()[0] : valueAccessor()[languageIndex] , allBindingsAccessor);            
        return ko.bindingHandlers.foreach.init(element, array, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext)
    {
        var languageIndex = self.displayLanguages.indexOf(self.currentLanguage());
        var array = ko.observableArray(languageIndex>valueAccessor().length-1? valueAccessor()[0] : valueAccessor()[languageIndex] , allBindingsAccessor);
        ko.bindingHandlers.foreach.update(element, array , allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);
        return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };       
    }
};
```